# unable to create a menu bar

Tags: html

```
<ul style="padding-left:0px;list-style:none">
<li style="display:inline"> <strong> Home </strong> </li>
<li style="display:inline;margin-left:40px"> <strong>Photos</strong> 
<ul style="padding-left:0px">
<li> find more </li>
<li> share more</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li style="display:inline;margin-left:40px"><strong> Edit </strong></li>
<li style="display:inline;margin-left:40px"><strong> Privacy </strong></li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

Could any one tell me where Im doing wrong?why the find more and share more options goes down the home tab but not below the photos tab ? and also any other listed options goes below the home tab but i want them to be placed one below the photos and other below the edit tab .Take a look at these http://jsfiddle.net/karthik_64/HXqeD/4/

I wanted it to be like these

```
  home   photos       edit          Privacy
         find more    zoom options 
         share more   more
```

Please help me with these.Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks niko

Comment: jsfiddle boxes are empty, are they ? or is it myself ?

Comment: sorry im new to jsfiddle if i do anything wrong excuse me!

Comment: I forgot to save them @dev I just updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about http://jsfiddle.net/dfNjA/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

`<li style="display:inline;margin-left:40px"> <strong>Photos</strong>`

With

`<li style="display:inline-block;margin-left:40px"> <strong>Photos</strong>`

will do the trick...

Comment: Thanks but take a look at these http://jsfiddle.net/karthik_64/HXqeD/6/  I wanted the home, photos, edit and privacy tabs to be on same line and options to go down but its different here